# Are hit percentages remotely accurate?

Tags: massive-chalice

The chance of missing 4-5 75%+ chances should be extremely low. However, it happens multiple times per mission. Since I'm playing on Brutal difficulty, this often results in someone dying.

I've checked and nobody has the Optimistic trait. There is no indication the chances shouldn't be correct, though there may of course be something I'm missing.

I am aware RNG means random but this doesn't seem close to what it should be. Is there something reducing chances not reflected in the percentages? If so, what should I expect from an 80% attack?

Comment: I have experienced this as well. Would be interested in a list of factors that affect accuracy positively and negatively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you point out, the [Optimist trait](http://massivechalice.gamepedia.com/Optimistic) essentially makes the hit rate estimates somewhat, well, optimistic. (Conversely the Pessimists underestimate their odds.) So let's assume for the moment the odds are correct. How likely is it to miss at those odds 4 to 5 times in mission?

75% means that 1 out of every 4 attacks results in a miss. If you attack 20 or so times in a mission, missing 5 times would be perfectly normal. Since each battle has 5 heros, twenty attacks works out to an average of 4 attacks per hero. That doesn't seem unreasonable since I often use all 5 flasks with my alchemists.  Obviously, some attacks will be more likely while others will be longer odds. But for the sake of argument, let's assume all attacks are exactly 75%. So missing 4 to 5 times a mission seems reasonable or even a bit too few.

Note that missing 4 to 5 times in a row is a lot less likely. Missing four times in a row is calculated:

```
0.25 * 0.25 * 0.25 * 0.25 = 0.25^4 = 0.00390625
```

Which is about 4 times in a thousand. That suggests a strategy: whenever possible, **arrange for your heros to support each other**. In other words, don't count on the first hero attacking to hit their target. Even at relatively high odds such as 90% to hit, it often pays to plan for another hero or two waiting in the wings. (Doubly so when attacks don't cause enough damage to remove the enemy's hit points.) Creating interlocking lines of fire happens to be the key to surviving squad-based games such as [X-COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-COM), [Close Combat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_Combat_(series)) and Massive Chalice.